# Move the ESXi service console from vmnic0 to vmnic1.123

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have an VMware ESXi 4.0.0 with 2 physical network cards. First one, vmnic0, has only the Service Console and the other one, vmnic1, is a trunk with all VLANs (including the management VLAN used by the Service Console). I would like to free vmnic0 port to be able to connect a network storage and I would like to move the management IP from vmnic0 to vmnic1/VLAN123.

Can I do this remotely? Is it possible from vSphere client? Should I do it from the ESXi console?

Comment: You surely mean vmnic0 and vmnic1, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best if you do this over the console, in case you lose the management network.

When at the console (this  is from memory) you press F2, and edit the management network settings.  There is a field for vlan and network adapters.

You can do it over the vSphere client too.  Under the host configuration, in network settings, add a new service console connection and add it to the vswtich using eth1; ensure you fill in the vlan field.

Connect to the new managment interface, and then under the network settings remove the old service console.

Comment: I have added a VMkernel on the vmnic1.123 from the vSphere Client. Thank you Steven.